# object callback function is undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

i have the following `object`

```
function AnimatedObject(object)
{
    this.object = object;
    /*
        Functions
     */
    this.fadeOutAnimation = fadeOutAnimation;
    this.objectToggle = objectToggle;
    this.objectClick = objectClick;
}
function fadeOutAnimation()
{
    this.object.animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: "+=150",
        height: "toggle"
    }, 2500, function() {
        this.objectToggle();
    });

}

function objectToggle()
{
    this.object.toggle();
}
```

From inside my `animate` function i am called `this.objectToggle();`

However when it completes the animation i get `undefined is not a function`

I am quite certian that it is because of the inner callback function that does not have a reference to the `object`

My question is how can i give it a reference to my object and thereby allow me to call its functions from inside the callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the function to the right context:

```
function fadeOutAnimation()
{
    this.object.animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: "+=150",
        height: "toggle"
    }, 2500, function() {
        this.objectToggle();
    }.bind(this));

}
```

Or just store a reference to `this`:

```
function fadeOutAnimation()
{
    var that = this;
    this.object.animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: "+=150",
        height: "toggle"
    }, 2500, function() {
        that.objectToggle();
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside animate function `this` refers to the animating div and context of the `this` has changed. you can bind this or can save reference earlier in the code

```
function fadeOutAnimation()
{
    that = this;
    this.object.animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: "+=150",
        height: "toggle"
    }, 2500, function() {
        that.objectToggle();
    });

}
```